# Why am I unable to assign a PowerPoint chart to a chart variable in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

At the moment, I'm just trying to follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889267/excel-xy-chart-scatter-plot-data-label-no-overlap)  but I've had this issue before. For some reason, I'm unable to assign PowerPoint charts to a declared Chart variable. Using .HasChart, I've confirmed that there is definitely a chart there, and using Shapes(i).Type, I've confirmed that the Shape is of a Chart Type, but I get Run-time error '13': Type mismatch every time. I've tried this in multiple files and multiple chart types, but to no avail - I must be missing something obvious and silly, but I can't figure it out.

For example:

```
Dim plot As Chart

For Each shp In PPT.Slides(5).Shapes

    If shp.HasChart Then

        MsgBox (shp.Type)
        Set plot = shp.Chart 

    End If

Next shp
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a `PowerPoint.Chart` is not the same as an `Excel.Chart` (see note below...). Try:

```
Dim plot As PowerPoint.Chart
```

When you do `Dim plot as Chart`, because `Chart` is a member of the `Excel` object model, VBA will default to use `Excel.Chart` unless otherwise specified.

The above assumes early binding with a reference to the PowerPoint library. If you get a compile error like "User-defined Type not Defined", this means you haven't set a project reference to PowerPoint. Alternatively, you can `Dim plot as Object` (generic object type) but you lose the intellisense that way.

NOTE: Functionally speaking, a `PowerPoint.Chart` is essentially identical to an `Excel.Chart` or a `Word.Chart`, etc., they will have the same methods, properties, etc., and with few exceptions (none that I can think of readily) anything you can do to one, you can do to the other. The only issue is that when you're referring to a chart that resides *within* PowerPoint, strictly speaking it is not an `Excel.Chart` and it needs to be qualified as `PowerPoint.Chart` (or generic `Object` type) to avoid the mismatch error.

Comment: Thank you! When I declare variables, the autofill gives me the option to select one of two Chart variables so I thought this was taken care of, but I guess not. Thanks for resolving a long unanswered question!

Comment: @tal yep, the two different `Chart`s are Excel and PowerPoint. Probably the Excel one will appear first in the list, but I'm not 100% sure about that :)

Comment: i've tried both selections from the drop-own but to no avail - I guess even with those there is still some ambiguity.

Comment: @tal that actually sounds about right, now that you mention it. I know I've had trouble with the `Series` and other object types that are shared across different MS Office applications.

Comment: Damn @DavidZemens how do you know so much about Power Point Charts?

Comment: @MichaelDavidWatson hahahahah